# Add Calendar Events From JSON Android

Tags: android, json, android-calendar

I am getting a json response which includes a date range `ex 2018-07-11 as start date and 2018-07-31 as end date`. Here's the full json response:

```
{
     "program_details": [
         {
             "batch_name": "batch testing",
             "batch_id": "41",
             "prg_name": "t4",
             "prg_id": "180",
             "prg_user_map_id": "175",
             "prg_start_date": "2018-04-15",
             "prg_end_date": "2018-04-21"
         },
        ]
}
```

I have the default calendar view widget from android studio in my xml and I am trying to show this date range from string into date and inserted into the calendar but I can't find the right methods to proceed with this.

I have seen the `google calendar api` but don't know how to get around this problem. Any help or links will be helpful. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Google calendar is very tricky

Here is my method for adding event to calendar of first user without any interaction:

```
public static long addEventToGoogleCalendar(Context context, HashMap<String, String> calendarAccauntsMap) {
    String eventUriString = "content://com.android.calendar/events";
    String reminderUriString = "content://com.android.calendar/reminders";

    ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();

    for(String key : calendarAccauntsMap.keySet()){
        if(key.equals(YOUR_USER_CALENDAR_EMAIL)){
            contentValues.put(CalendarContract.Events.CALENDAR_ID, Integer.parseInt(key));
        }
    }

    contentValues.put(CalendarContract.Events.TITLE, YOUR_EVENT_NAME); //batch_name

    contentValues.put(CalendarContract.Events.EVENT_TIMEZONE, TimeZone.getDefault().getID());
    contentValues.put(CalendarContract.Events.DTSTART, YOUR_DATE_START_IN_MS); //prg_start_date in ms
    contentValues.put(CalendarContract.Events.DTEND, YOUR_DATE_END_IN_MS); //prg_end_date in ms
    contentValues.put(CalendarContract.Events.ALL_DAY, 0); 
    contentValues.put(CalendarContract.Events.STATUS, CalendarContract.Events.STATUS_CONFIRMED);

    Uri eventUri = context.getContentResolver().insert(Uri.parse(eventUriString), contentValues);
    long eventID = Long.parseLong(eventUri.getLastPathSegment());

    ContentValues reminderValues = new ContentValues();

    reminderValues.put(CalendarContract.Reminders.EVENT_ID, eventID);

    reminderValues.put(CalendarContract.Reminders.METHOD, CalendarContract.Reminders.METHOD_ALERT); // Alert Methods: Default(0),

    context.getContentResolver().insert(Uri.parse(reminderUriString), reminderValues);

    return eventID;
}
```

Where `calendarAccauntsMap` is map of user id's, that can be found like this -

```
public static HashMap<String, String> getCalendarAccounts(Context context) {
        String projection[] = {"_id", "calendar_displayName"};
        Cursor managedCursor = context.getContentResolver()
                .query(Uri.parse("content://com.android.calendar/calendars"), projection, null, null, null);

        HashMap<String, String> calendarMap = new HashMap<>();
        if (managedCursor != null) {
            if (managedCursor.moveToFirst()) {
                String calName;
                String calID;
                int nameCol = managedCursor.getColumnIndex(projection[1]);
                int idCol = managedCursor.getColumnIndex(projection[0]);
                do {
                    calName = managedCursor.getString(nameCol);
                    calID = managedCursor.getString(idCol);
                    if (calName.matches(emailRegex)) {
                        calendarMap.put(calID, calName);
                    }
                } while (managedCursor.moveToNext());
                managedCursor.close();
            }
        }
        return calendarMap;
    }
```

Comment: Elegant code but I have a few doubts like do I need to use RxJava for the Observable part and how does it set the date range from json? If you can give some explanation to your code, I'll accept this answer. Thank you so much.

Comment: See comments in my code. Also no reason to use RX. I will rewrite it in few minutes

Comment: Okay, please do. Thanks

Comment: @Andromeda check again

Comment: Your code seems workable but the issue here now is I don't have the user_calendar_email and while calling the method addEventtoGoogleCalendar(this, Object, map), what should the object be?

Comment: Can this work without the users being signed in?Thanks

Comment: I removed Object event, it is unused. About user. You could remove `calName.matches(emailRegex)` so you will get all device callendars, not only user calendar. I cant remeber, old project, but if you debug, you will see what ids you have there. I think there should be some default id.

Comment: Does this require a calendarview in xml? If possible can you share a github gist with this working implementation? Thank you sir

Comment: @Andromeda I am not familar with Gists. This code adds event to your device system calendar

Comment: I want this calendar to be exclusive to the app, if that's not possible, thank you sir for your time.